# Attribute Not Updating

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

**Model**

```
class Pm < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :name
end
```

**Console**

```
me = Pm.new
  #=> <Pm id: nil, name: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
me.name = "Josh"
  #=> "Josh"
me.save
  #=>(0.4ms)  BEGIN
  #=> true
  #=> SQL (0.8ms)  INSERT INTO "pms" ("created_at", "name", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", Sat, 01 Jun 2013 19:02:27 UTC +00:00], ["name", nil], ["updated_at", Sat, 01 Jun 2013 19:02:27 UTC +00:00]]
  #=>(1.3ms)  COMMIT
me
  #=> <Pm id: 4, name: nil, created_at: "2013-06-01 19:02:27", updated_at: "2013-06-01 19:02:27">
```

I have a model with a `name` attribute and an `attr_accessor` defined. The record saves but it doesn't update the `name` attribute.  Am I missing something simple here?

Comment: Can you please copy/paste from your console instead of a tiny image of its contents? Obviously we'll also need to see the code.

Comment: Sorry I didn't realize how small it would be, I have edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `Pmp` model ("Pimp"? "Pump"? "Pimple"?) has a DB field called "name", there's no reason to use `attr_accessor :name`. With `attr_accessor :name`, ActiveRecord's dynamically generated attribute methods will never be invoked, and yes, it means the attribute won't be saved to the database.

Comment: I see. I was having trouble trying to imagine what a pimp-management or pimple-management app would look like...